# SQL creating a pivot function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL code that looks like this:

```
select cast(avg(age) as decimal(16,2)) as 'avg' From

(select distinct acct.Account, cast(Avg(year(getdate())- year(client_birth_date)) as decimal(16,2)) as 'Age' 
     from       WF_PM_ACCT_DB            DET
     inner join WF_PM_ACCT_DET_DB        ACCT
     ON det.Account = acct.Account
     where (acct_closing_date is null or acct_closing_date > '2017-01-01')
     and Acct_Open_Date < '2017-01-01'

 group by acct.Account
 ) x
```

Then basically what this give me is a simple one cell answer of the average age of accounts in the year  Acct_Open_Date < '2017-01-01' . I am an ameture so i change the date everytime and run the query again and again to get the remaining year. Is there an easy way to say lets have all the years as column headings and just one row with the average account age in that year.

Please note that the account closing date being null means accounts never got close and i have to change it to less than the analysis year in order to get a true picture of the average account age that existed at that time

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run this for multiple dates by including them in a single derived table:

```
with dates as (
      select cast('2017-01-01' as date) as yyyy union all
      select cast('2016-01-01' as date)
     )
select yyyy, cast(avg(age) as decimal(16,2)) as avg_age
From (select dates.yyyy, acct.Account,
             cast(Avg(year(getdate())- year(client_birth_date)) as decimal(16,2)) as Age
     from dates cross join
          WF_PM_ACCT_DB DET inner join WF_PM_ACCT_DET_DB
          ACCT
          on det.Account = acct.Account
     where (acct_closing_date is null or acct_closing_date > dates.yyyy) and
           Acct_Open_Date < dates.yyyy
     group by acct.Account, dates.yyyy
    ) x
group by yyyy
order by yyyy;
```

Comment: Thank you for that. It really helps

Comment: How does the cross join function here? i am reading online and it say's that cross join will result in all possible combination of the rows. However can you explain what logic you were thinking? For the next similar problem i face how do i know a cross join should be used?

Comment: @DataGuy . . . Think of it as running your original query for each date.